# Can't select text in contenteditable in Chrome by using keyboard

Tags: html, google-chrome, contenteditable

In Chrome, I can't select the contenteditable text context by using the keyboard in Chrome when the text contains a long string that wraps to the next line.

This repro's in Chrome (latest; Chrome 47 at the time of my writing this).

**Repro steps**

1. Click to place the cursor at the *end* of the contentedtable div (in the snippet below).
2. Hold shift and hit the up arrow a bunch of times.

**Expected**: All text becomes selected.

**Observed**: The text before the space ("foo") is never selected.

Here's the code. NOTE the character after "foo" is a space, not a newline!

```html
<div contenteditable="true" style="background: #ddd; width: 200px; height: 100px;">foo asdfjkl;asdfjkl;asdfjkl;asdfjkl;asdfjkl;asdfjkl;asdfjkl;</div>
```

Comment: jsyk, you can still select it by pressing shift and the left arrow, just not the up arrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, that's the correct behavior of textboxes in general.

In this case, you see the two words in different lines because the second one is wider than the container, so you see a line break and you try to use the `up arrow` to select "foo".

But, as you say in the question, after "foo" there is a space character, so you must use the `left arrow` to select it.

*Just imagine the same case but with a full width textbox, you would only try to use the `left arrow`. Only the style changes here, not the behavior for that specific content.*

Comment: Interesting, you're right. The same thing does seem to happen with textareas in Chrome. However it works as I expected in Firefox (with both contenteditables and textareas).