# Can't select last word of two spans with contentEditable using CTRL + Right Arrow

Tags: html, select, text

I can't select the last word of two spans with contentEditable using CTRL + Right Arrow.

Is this a bug, or it is supposed to work like that?

Is there any way to make it work?

```html
<span contenteditable="true">Can't select the last word of this span with with CTRL + Right Arrow => lastWord</span>

<span contenteditable="true"> Did you see? You're not being able to reach the final of the previous span with CTRL + Arrow<span>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't select text in contenteditable in Chrome by using keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366899/cant-select-text-in-contenteditable-in-chrome-by-using-keyboard)

Comment: @MeherUllahKhanRaj No, first, it is a different problem, my problem it requires two or more editablecontents instead of one to replicate. Second, if I try to replicate his issue, it works as he expected to work, all text is being selected, no issue. You can replicate my issue, and you'll see that it will always work as I described.

Comment: Reported the bug in chromium: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1296388